# Obtaining groups and counts at the same time

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

Suppose my table looks like this:

```
Name City Salary
n1   c1   10
n1   c1   20
n1   c1   30
n2   c2   20
n2   c2   50
n3   c2   70
```

And I am interested in the following output:

```
Name Count 
n1   3 
n2   2  
n3   1
```

I am fairly new to SQL and have been doing similar commands in SAS (e.g. in this case I would have used PROC FREQ) - but I am now required to write the same code only in the SQL language (I am using Aginity Netezza).

Comment: You should read up on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

If its MySQL, or any fairly standard SQL:

```
SELECT Name, Count(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY Name
```